# geom_dotplot dot layout with groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

The dotplot that I am trying to create is shown below.  The dots have been laid out using a couple of different options.

```
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)

set.seed(10000)
n <- 300

dt <- data.table(Duration=sample(100:800,n,replace=T), EndType=round(runif(n,min=.4)), Group=sample(c("GrpA","GrpB"),n,replace=T))
dt <- rbind(dt, dt[, -c("Group"), with=F][, Group:="All"])
dt[, ":="(Group=factor(Group, levels=c("All","GrpA","GrpB"), ordered=T), EndType=factor(EndType, levels=c(0,1)))]

#option 1 - creates space between dots which are filled and not filled
g <- ggplot(dt, aes_string(x="Group", y="Duration")) + coord_flip() +
    geom_boxplot(aes(ymin=..lower.., ymax=..upper..), fatten=1.1, lwd=.1, outlier.shape=NA) + 
    geom_dotplot(aes(fill=EndType), binaxis="y", stackdir="center", stackgroups=T, method="histodot", binwidth=15, dotsize=.5) +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("white","black"))
print(g)

#option 2 - extends to the other bar when there are many of one type
g <- ggplot(dt, aes_string(x="Group", y="Duration")) + coord_flip() +
    geom_boxplot(aes(ymin=..lower.., ymax=..upper..), fatten=1.1, lwd=.1, outlier.shape=NA) + 
    geom_dotplot(data=dt[EndType==1], aes(fill=EndType), fill="black", binaxis="y", stackdir="up", method="histodot", binwidth=15, dotsize=.5) +
    geom_dotplot(data=dt[EndType==0], aes(fill=EndType), fill="white", binaxis="y", stackdir="down", method="histodot", binwidth=15, dotsize=.5)
print(g)
```

Is there a way of laying out the dots (black and white) so that they are together like in option 2 but centered across the line?

**Option 1**
[image]

**Option 2**
[image]

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.1.0    data.table_1.9.7

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] labeling_0.3     colorspace_1.2-6 scales_0.4.0     plyr_1.8.4       gtable_0.2.0    
[6] Rcpp_0.12.6      grid_3.3.1       digest_0.6.10    munsell_0.4.3
```

Comment: Your option 2 errors for me: `Error in bmerge(i, x, leftcols, rightcols, io <- FALSE, xo, roll = 0,  : 
  x.'EndType' is a factor column being joined to i.'V1' which is type 'double'. Factor columns must join to factor or character columns.`

Comment: That is a data.table issue (https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1361).   I have just added my sessionInfo.  You many need to update your `data.table`.

Comment: The error is not a big deal anyway. I am right that your question basically boils down to: 'why does option 1 give me a weird result'?

Comment: Yes!  And how do I fix it ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I think you may have run into a bug. I'm not sure why the stacking of groups is going wrong in your first option. Perhaps others can weigh in. You might want to search for, and otherwise report, this issue [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues).

Here is a quick workaround that *does* work, instead of multiple dotplots on one  axes we use facets:

```
ggplot(dt, aes_string(x=1, y="Duration")) + coord_flip() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(ymin=..lower.., ymax=..upper..), fatten=1.1, lwd=.1, outlier.shape=NA) + 
  geom_dotplot(aes(fill=EndType), binaxis="y", stackdir="center", stackgroups=T, method="histodot", binwidth=15, dotsize=.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("white","black")) +
  facet_grid(Group~.)
```

[image]

Comment: Good workaround.  You could switch the strips and mess with themes to make this look even more like a graph without facets.  A start: `facet_grid(Group~., switch = "y") + theme(panel.margin.y = unit(0, "lines"), panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.length = unit(0, "lines"))`